# Can a Winsock TCP connection between server and client resume as-was after the server must restart?

Tags: tcp, winsock

Is there a way to save the "state" of Winsock so that the server program can be stopped and restarted and all the client TCP connections continue as though nothing happened, without the clients having to do anything special?

Or is it the case that once a Winsock server process terminates, client connections can only be reestablished through all the usual initialization calls?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A lost/closed connection must be re-established through a new connect handshake.  So if you don't want the client to know the server is restarted, you will have to move the existing connection to another process first, then move it back after the restart.  You can use [`WSADuplicateSocket()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms741565.aspx) for that.

Comment: It is possible. It's been done before. It's just an awful lot of work and, to my knowledge, nobody has bothered to do it on Windows.

Comment: I have never heard of anyone doing this on any system, let alone on Windows.  There are APIs to query active connections (`GetTcpTable()`, etc), but AFAIK there are no APIs to create custom-defined connections. Even if you could, sequence numbers and such are likely to be out of sync.

Comment: In principle at least, I think it should be possible to launch a temporary process, use WSADuplicateSocket to make a copy of the sockets in the temporary process, restart the server, then use WSADuplicateSocket again to copy the sockets to the new instance of the server.

Comment: I suppose that is one way to do it.  I have updated my answer.